# std::string in object being deleted during push_back to std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdstring

i have a class with a std::string in it. The class itself is completely fine, but the problem is that I have another class which have a std::vector of the first one in it. The point is, in the constructor of the second class, I load some names from the file, I try to push_back a object of the first class to the vector in the second one. The objects of the first class are contructed perfectly(I tried reading the std::string in them) but when they are pushed to the vector, the string just disappears! I tried using emplace_back but that didn't help either. Here's the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class CItemTemplate {
protected:
    char id;
    std::string name;
public:
    CItemTemplate ():id(0),name(""){};
    CItemTemplate (char _id, std::string _name) : id(_id){name = _name;};
    CItemTemplate (const CItemTemplate& pattern) {id = pattern.GetID();}
    ~CItemTemplate (){};

    char GetID() const {return id;};
    std::string GetName() {return name;}
    //sf::Texture* GetTexture() const {return tekstura;}
};

class CItemSystem {
    std::vector<CItemTemplate> item_list;
public:
    CItemSystem(std::string fpthItems);
    ~CItemSystem(){}


    void list() {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < item_list.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << (int)item_list[i].GetID() << " " << item_list[i].GetName() << std::endl << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
CItemSystem::CItemSystem(std::string fpthItems){
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(fpthItems);
    if (!file.is_open()) std::cout << "error!\n";
    char name[64];
    CItemTemplate tempitem;
    item_list.push_back(CItemTemplate());
    std::cout << "loading items...\n\n";
    for (int i = 1;!file.eof();++i) {
        file.getline(name,64,'|');
        std::cout << CItemTemplate(i,(std::string)name).GetName() << std::endl << std::endl;
        item_list.push_back(CItemTemplate(i,(std::string)name));

    }
    file.close();
}

int main()
{
    CItemSystem ItemSystem("items.txt");

    std::cout << "writing list of items...\n\n";

    ItemSystem.list();

    return 0;
}
};
CItemSystem::CItemSystem(std::string fpthItems){
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(fpthItems);
    if (!file.is_open()) std::cout << "error!\n";
    char name[64];
    CItemTemplate tempitem;
    item_list.push_back(CItemTemplate());
    std::cout << "loading items...\n\n";
    for (int i = 1;!file.eof();++i) {
        file.getline(name,64,'|');
        std::cout << CItemTemplate(i,(std::string)name).GetName() << std::endl << std::endl;
        item_list.push_back(CItemTemplate(i,(std::string)name));

    }
    file.close();
}
CItem CItemSystem::Item(char id) {
    return (CItem(item_list[id]));
}

int main()
{
    CItemSystem ItemSystem("items.txt");

    CItem przedmiota = ItemSystem.Item(2);
    CItem przedmiotb = ItemSystem.Item(4);

    std::cout << "writing list of items...\n\n";

    ItemSystem.list();

    return 0;
}
```

The result:

> loading items...
>
> Bottle
>
> Plug
>
> Plugged bottle
>
> Water
>
> Unplugged bottle of water
>
> Plug with water
>
> Bottle of water
>
> writing list of items...
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7
>
> 8

The przedmioty.txt file:

> Bottle|Plug|Plugged bottle|Water|Plugged bottle of water|Plug with water|Bottle of water|

Comment: The class itself is not completely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy constructor (the one taking a `const CItemTemplate&`) is implemented incorrectly: it doesn't copy the name.